# Is there any way to correct uneven bed temperature?

Tags: creality-ender-3, heated-bed, thermistor, glass-bed

I'm using an Ender 3 Pro with stock heated bed & glass build surface on it (without any base of stock magnetic plate). My heated bed looks completely flat too despite of many uneven Ender 3 heated beds around.

But when bed temperature set to 70 °C and I check the temperature of bed with infrared laser thermometer gun, the front of the bed is around 72 °C and the back is around 64-68 °C. So the temperature is different at all sides and this looks like leading to warps too.

Is there any way to make it more even for all bed surface?

Comment: you can add insulation to the bottom of the bed. My CR10 had some, but it didn't go to the edges, so the edges would sink heat away and run cooler. I just stuck old double-stick foam on there, but there's kits you can buy. My DIY fix killed more than half of the diff, so i was pleased. It also helps just to pre-heat the whole thing longer to allow temps to stabilize deep in the mass.

Comment: I guess the tradeoff is the more you insulate the bed the slower it will cool down.

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact issue with my Qidi X-Plus. After checking with a thermometer there was a spread of 9°C - enough to burn in (always the same) certain areas when printing at higher extremes of temperatures, or causing poor adhesion in other certain areas at lower temps. Very similar scenario too, I noticed this primarily when switching over to glass from the stock magnetic plate.

My solution was quite straightforward - I set the bed temperature on the printer's control panel and preheated it before sending it a print. As long as I left it there for a solid 10 minutes after getting up to temperature it balanced within around 1°C. I observed far more consistent results from print to print.

Now I don't know your exact machine myself, so I don't know if this is possible on the control panel on an Ender 3. However if it's not, as an alternative possibly consider looking up how to stick a pause in the initial gcode in Cura to see if you can achieve the same effect.

Comment: Great tip!  Tried it on my E3, got a smooth first layer.  Thanks!          Control, temperature, bed